# Custom dictionary through **kw

Tags: python

I have a library function that makes use of `**kw`, but I want to pass a dictionary-like class so that I can override `__getitem__` to track its accesses to data in the dictionary.  For example, in the code below calling libfn does not print Accessed but libfn2 does.

```
class Dtracker(dict):
  def __init__(self):
    dict.__init__(self)
  def __getitem__(self,item):
    print "Accessed %s" % str(item)
    return dict.__getitem__(self, item)


def libfn(**kw):
  a = kw["foo"]
  print "a is %s" % a
  return a

def libfn2(kw):
  a = kw["foo"]
  print "a is %s" % a
  return a

d = Dtracker()
d["foo"] = "bar"  
libfn(**d)
libfn2(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
class Dtracker(dict):
    def __init__(self,*arg,**kw):
        super(Dtracker,self).__init__(*arg,**kw)
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        print "Accessed %s" % str(item)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

def track( fn ):
    def tracked_fn( **kw ):
        kw= Dtracker( kw )
        fn( kw )
    return tracked_fn

@track
def libfn(kw):
    a = kw["foo"]
    print "a is %s" % a
    return a
```

This more-or-less works

```
>>> libfn( **{'foo':'bar'} )
Accessed foo
a is bar
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although the 1st response "you can't" seems to be technically correct, this answer gets me where I want to go with the fewest changes -- most importantly no API changes.  I'll just have to hack the library *sigh*.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, without changing Python itself. It's converted to a `dict` at a lower level.